# Add empty first row in smart field

Tags: drop-down-menu, eclipse-scout

in eclipse scout mars:

how to add empty row in smart field, so user can select nothing and he is not forced to select some value in smart field.

In sql if I add SELECT 0, '' UNION SELECT id, name FROM users...is working ok, empty row is show, but in modify value is not populated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if Eclipse Scout supports this construct of a row having an empty text.

The way to clear a value in a SmartField is to delete the text. In this case the value of the SmartField is set to `null`. If the value is not mandatory the user can save the form.

- Can you check if this would work with your example.
- Can you check if it would work if you add some text associated with your `0` value. Something like `"(empty)"` or `"---"`